# Remix - Multiple dynamic segments matching single path

Tags: remix.run

I'm building an app with many dynamic paths involved, but Remix only support single dynamic path out of the box. I searched the docs but can't find anything that would allow me to achieve the following.

My Route structure looks like this:

```bash
$postType
- $collectionType
- - $id.tsx
- - index.tsx
- $id.tsx
- index.tsx
```

So it's basically a structure of post and collection types that gives me possible paths like this:

- `/books` - renders `$postType/index.tsx`
- `/books/the-shining` - renders `$postType/$id.tsx` dynamically
- `/books/authors` - renders `$postType/$collectionType/index.tsx`
- `/books/authors/steven-king` - renders `$postType/$collectionType/$id.tsx` dynamically

Unfortunately, out of the box, it takes only the first dynamic path it finds, so `/books/the-shining` would point to the `$postType/$collectionType/index.tsx` file.

Is there any way to tell Remix from the loader, that the collection type with that slug was not found and to go to another dynamic path?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix tries to match the longest route. Since `/books/the-shining` and `/books/authors` are ambiguous, Remix can only choose the longest route.

You will need to either update your route structure to give Remix a hint:

`$postType.c.$collectionType.index.tsx` -> `/books/c/authors`

Or you can use a splat `$.tsx` route as a catch-all, then dynamically parse the URL to determine which layout/route to render.

```js
export function loader({request, params}: LoaderArgs) {
  const splat = params['*']
  const parts = splat.split('/')
  //...
}
```

---

There is an RFC for optional route segments that will first be in React Router and will eventually make it to Remix.

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9550